# Preferred Vector Image format for use in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vector, raster, image-formats

As per the title, what's the preferred image format (or formats) for use in WPF?

My company will hire a designer to design some logos, images, toolbar icons, etc. for use in a WPF application. I was going to ask for Vector Graphics as they are supposed to stretch, shrink, etc without loosing clarity;

However, reading this post
[Does WPF support reading/writing WMF/EMF files natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554492/does-wpf-support-reading-writing-wmf-emf-files-natively)
and others has got me worried; IT DOES NOT SEEM LIKE A SIMPLE TASK?! isn't this what WPF is supposed to handle natively in its sleep ?! stretch, rotate, throw flames, make toast, etc...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The preferred vector image format is XAML. There are a lot of ways for a designer to generate those graphics. Adoble Illustrator for example can use the [XAML exporter](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/). The open source tool [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/?lang=de) can export to XAML directly, a designer can also draw XAML using [Microsoft Expression Design](http://www.microsoft.com/germany/Expression/products/design_overview.aspx) and [Microsoft Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx). Literally all vector graphics tool support SVG and there are [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764/xaml-to-svg) of [ways](http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/) to convert SVG to XAML.

Don't bother with WMF/EMF it will just look ugly since windows can not render them antialiased.

Comment: GDI+ can render metafiles antialiased, but only if they were EMF+ metafiles created by GDI+. It's a mess. Yes, XAML would be a much better way to go.