# Create Vector image from WPF View

Tags: wpf

Is it possible (and if so how) to take a WPF view and create a vector image from it.

Currently the application I am working on does two things:
1. Prints the dialogs using the built in `PrintDialog` and `XpsDocumentWriter` classes.
2. Saves the dialogs to Tiff files using the built in classes from Microsoft.

How can one save a WPF dialog to a high quality vector file?

The end goal is to end up in a high quality PDF or Tiff file.  Though in my reading Tiff files are not really vector files, is this incorrect?

Comment: Any particular format of vector file you are looking for? TIFF, PSD are some of the more common layered/vector formats but there are quite a few available. You need to know exactly what you want out of your program before recommendations can be provided!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554492/does-wpf-support-reading-writing-wmf-emf-files-natively

Comment: Drew, thanks for the comment.  I've put a little more in the question.  My biggest struggle here is that I don't want to ask the completely wrong question, as I'm not sure what information is fully relevant to the needed answer here.